# Specify query for datagridfilter sonata

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

When using the `doctrine_orm_model` type for the datagridfilter. Is there a way to define a custom query to fetch the possible filter values?

Lets say I do not want to load all the entities for that specific type. I can not find any way to specify a query or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can like this your admin class. Important is 5 parameter, with query builder.

```
protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
{
    $datagridMapper->add('modelField', null, [], 'entity', [
            'class' => 'App\Entity\YourModel',
            'choice_label' => 'name', // or something else as label
            'query_builder' => function(YourModelRepository $repository) {
                // return your query builder
            }
        ]
    );     
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Did not know you could do it like that. thank you verry much.